# How can I style a feature that has multiple values for the same field?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, style

I'm opening a PostgreSQL Table on QGIS which has multiple rows related to the same object (think of how you'd register distinct apartments on the same building).

I do get to style it based on any of it's columns, but at the same time I know that some of the objects have distinct values for some of the fields (valuation, for example).

Which of the rows is QGIS taking the value on which the style is based?

Comment: it should be using all of them! in the case of spatially coincident apartments, you just won't see the apartments below the top one - which you can set using symbol levels...

Comment: Mhhhh, and what about Labels, shouldn't both work the same way? When I label the object only one of the rows gets labeled.

Comment: I would have to guess it's because there are too many colliding labels, so QGIS isn't displaying them... there is an option to 'show all labels, including colliding' which you can check on...

Comment: You have nailed it my friend, when I check the 'including coliding' box, all labels, well, collide. Is there a way to represent this in a readable manner?

Comment: And the same with styling, I'm trying to map how the apartments in each bulding have been valuated. I'd probably need to use some sort of 3D cadastre or even split each object and then assign the rows to the result. But maybe there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Right - check out the QGIS2threejs plugin which might be a good start or this example: http://opensourcegisblog.blogspot.com/2014/03/3d-visualization-of-manhattan-using.html but you might need to create some base elevations and heights to get this to work (another sql problem perhaps?)